Are there any studies about scientific consensus about climate change solutions?
There are studies demonstrating the high level of scientific consensus around the existence of climate change among scientists, and how this is related to their publishing record.
Are there any such papers analysing the extent of the agreement that exists about what action the world should take to combat climate change?  I am thinking about attitude to things like nuclear power, electric cars, geoengineering and degrowth.

I think this is mainly an economic debate, not scientific debate. And generally you can't expect that scientific papers make reliable cost estimates for example.
If a scientific paper in a reputable journal says we can construct 17.3 PWh of pumped storage hydropower, we can generally expect this claim to be valid. It has to have proof to convince the reviewers that sites for constructing such pumped storage exist.
But if a scientific paper says that we can do so below a cost of 50 USD / MWh, this claim has to be taken with a grain of salt. The reviewers in scientific journals generally can't validate such a claim, as they often work in academia and the most reliable information about cost estimates is available in private businesses.
(Here's the paper I'm referring to: https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-020-14555-y)
The problem here is that what action should be taken depends on costs.
Maybe solar power wins. (I think it'll win in areas where it isn't heavily seasonal, i.e. most populated areas.)
Maybe wind power wins. (I think it'll win in sparsely populated northern areas where solar power isn't available much in winter.)
Maybe nuclear power wins. (It has the massive benefit of being very reliable baseload, but the problem is construction of new reactors is expensive and they have to compete in a volatile electricity market where electricity is practically free often.)
Maybe battery energy storage wins. (I think it'll win only in areas where solar power isn't heavily seasonal.)
Maybe pumped storage hydro wins. (I'm not sure about that, as the construction costs are uncertain, maybe hydrogen could be a better option.)
Maybe hydrogen underground storage wins. (I'm not sure about that, as the construction costs are uncertain, maybe pumped storage hydro could be a better option.)
Maybe energy is mostly stored as heat in large scale (created using electric resistance hyeaters), in areas where heating is needed and district heating networks are available. Maybe heat storage has the problem that it can't be converted back to electricity with good efficiency so other energy storage options like batteries, hydrogen or pumped storage hydro are better.
Maybe electrolysis cells become so cheap that electrolysis is a dynamic load, adjusted according to momentary power production. Maye electrolysis cells remain so expensive that it's more economical to run them 24/7.
Maybe hydrogen will be converted to electricity in gas turbines. Maybe in internal combustion engine power plants. Maybe fuel cell prices reduce markedly and their reliability increases so much that everyone wants to use fuel cells instead of the older more mature technologies.
Maybe cars of the future are all electric cars. Maybe fuel cell prices reduce so much that hydrogen fuel cell vehicles make a surprise comeback with pricing that will be competitive, and offering far better range than electric vehicles.
Maybe ships of the future will run on liquified hydrogen. Maybe ammonia. Maybe e-fuels with carbon capture using either amines or as carbonates. Most likely nuclear is too expensive.
Maybe planes of the future will run on liquified hydrogen. Maybe ammonia. Maybe e-fuels, but without carbon capture as carbon capture equipment is too heavy and large for planes.
Maybe heating will be done mostly using ground source heat pumps, in a distributed manner.
Maybe heating will be done mostly using district heating, allowing large-scale heat storage and utilization of large waste heat sources. Maybe the most important district heating source is heat pumps (maybe using seawater heat or waste heat sources). Maybe it's resistance heaters that are run only when electricity spot price is cheap, and then the energy is stored in large underground caves as heated water.
The fact is, we don't know. There are solutions. What will win in a free market economy is the cheapest solution.
I think lots of businesses that bet the wrong horse will fail.
But if you want to know details about particular technologies such as electrolysis, solar panels, etc. the scientific literature has that available. But it doesn't have reliable cost estimates. And cost estimates are massively important of the details on what action has to be taken.
However, on one thing scientists are generally unanimous: carbon dioxide should have a worldwide price that applies to all emissions and sinks, in all contries, equally. If I have a forest that grows and absorbs carbon dioxide, I should get a payment for the absorbed carbon dioxide. If I chop the forest down to make pulpwood, I should pay (or someone should pay) for the rapidly released carbon dioxide. If I make long-lived wood products, the payment for released carbon dioxide should be only made when they will be disposed and burned.
Today the situation is ridiculous. Agriculture and forestry don't generally belong to carbon trading so growing forest isn't an economic benefit for the forest owner and farmers can convert forest into fields for growing crops, even if that releases carbon dioxide, for free.
As a Finnish carowner, I pay probably more than 300 EUR of each carbon dioxide tonne that I emit, but the emission trading price for those sectors that use it in EU is about 70 EUR.
